# SML datatype match redundant produces redundancy

Tags: types, sml

I have this from *The Little MLer*

```
datatype 'a pizza =
         Bottom
         | Topping of ('a * ('a pizza))
```

and this

```
datatype fish =
         Anchovy
         | Lox
       | Tuna
```

and this working code

```
fun rem_fish (f, fp) =
    let
        fun eq_fish (Anchovy,Anchovy) = true
          | eq_fish (Lox,Lox) = true
          | eq_fish (Tuna,Tuna) = true
          | eq_fish (_,_) = false
    in
        case fp of
            Bottom => Bottom
          | Topping(x,y) =>
            case eq_fish (f,x) of
                true => rem_fish (f,y)
              | false => Topping (x,rem_fish (f,y))
end
```

which will take a fish type and a fish pizza pair and remove that particular fish in the first argument

```
- rem_fish (Tuna, Topping (Tuna, (Topping (Anchovy, Topping (Lox, Topping (Tuna, Bottom))))));
Topping (Anchovy,Topping (Lox,Bottom)) : fish pizza
```

Good, so I then see this code (which I've changed to be `case` based) marked as "ungrammatical"

```
fun rem_fish (f, fp) =
        case fp of
            Bottom => Bottom
          | Topping (f,fp') => rem_fish (f,fp')
          | Topping (x,fp') => Topping (x,rem_fish (f,fp'))
```

but this error

```
Error: match redundant
:           Bottom => ...
:           Topping (f,fp') => ...
:     -->   Topping (x,fp') => ...
```

What does this error mean? What's wrong with the code? The last line could have been something like this

```
Topping (_,fp') => Topping (?,rem_fish (f,fp'))
```

but then I don't know what `?` could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may become clearer if we eliminate some unneeded shadowing in this code.
Consider the function

```ml
fun rem_fish (f, fp) =
        case fp of
            Bottom => Bottom
          | Topping (y,fp') => rem_fish (y,fp')
          | Topping (x,fp') => Topping (x,rem_fish (f,fp'))
```

which is equivalent to what you've written.

Notice that both `Topping (y,fp')` and `Topping (x,fp')` are irrefutable patterns for a `Topping` variant; they'll always match it. So in your code, if you have a `Topping` it will match the second branch of your `case` always, and thus the third branch is redundant (what the error is saying).

If you want to be able to check if the first element in the tuple wrapped by `Topping` is equal to `f`, you'll either need to explicitly do so with `op=` (forcing it to be an equality type), or take some sort of equality function as a parameter to check with (or have it internally as you do in the initial example). The latter might look something like

```ml
fun rem_fish (_, Bottom) _ = Bottom
  | rem_fish (f, Topping (x, fp)) cmp = 
      if cmp (f, x) then
        rem_fish (f, fp)
      else
        Topping (x, rem_fish (f, fp))
```

(which can then be a bit more general for toppings other than fish that have equality functions)

Comment: But why is the `f` in my second branch `| Topping (f,fp') =>...` not matching on the incoming argument `f`? Sure, with `Topping (y,fp')` and `Topping (x,fp')` the `x` and the `y` are interchangeable, i.e., SML doesn't think match on`y`, then match on not-y `x`. But, again, `f` is the variable of the incoming `fish` to match on.

Comment: The `f` in the case branch is just a new (irrefutable) pattern; it is _not_ the same `f` that is an argument. Similarly to how you can't have a function like `fn (x, x) => true | _ => false` that matches the first case when both elements of the tuple are the same (though this one is caught with an error), SML has no idea how you would compare to see that those are equal. Consider the type of your `rem_fish` with the redundant match: you're trying to compare any two values of type `'a` for equality in the case; that doesn't really make sense. You need some way to enable that comparison.

Comment: The original "ungrammatical" version in the book gives `... | rem_fish(x,Topping(x,p)) = rem_fish(x,p) ...` which has this same issue, producing the same error `duplicate variable in pattern(s): x`.